# ERROR : 'va_start' used in function with fixed args - C/SGDK

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a very strange issue with  variadic functions in C with SGDK, here is my code:

```
void create_cinematic(int type, ...)
{
  // Pointer to list of arguments
  va_list argp;
  // Start reading arguments
  va_start(argp, type);
  // Stop reading arguments
  va_end(argp);
}
```

I call it in my main :

```
create_cinematic(0, 1, 2);
```

But all I got when I compile is this error message :

**error: 'va_start' used in function with fixed args
   va_start(argp, type);**

Do you have any idea ? The strange thing is that if I do :

```
create_cinematic("foo", 1, 2);
```

I got the warning :

**warning: passing argument 1 of 'create_cinematic' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   create_cinematic("foo", 1, 2);**

**note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'char *'
 void create_cinematic(int type, ...);**

But it compiles and it works !

I'm completely lost about this, thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you include `<stdarg.h>`?

Comment: The error message clearly does not correspond to the code that you've posted, so it is likely that you are not compiling the file that you think you are.  Without the *exact* file contents and command line you are using, its unlikely anyone here can help.